# Need scrollIntoView() only within a nested component, not the entire page Javascript, React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am working on a React project with a messaging component nested inside a show component. I am trying to bring the scroll within the messaging component to the last message by using the scrollIntoView javascript function. However, when the function is called, the entire show component page is focused on the message, when I want the page when rendered to start at the top, and just have the last message be the focus only of that component.

I have tried breaking up the components and rendering messaging inside the show component, then calling scrollIntoView there, but that does not work.

Is there a way to bring the scroll only within the component and not the entire page itself? Any hints or direction would be appreciated.

The code for the components are quite long and not that relevant so I can simplify it if needed.

I am using the following function inside the nested messaging component:

```
  scrollLastMessageIntoView() {
    const items = document.querySelectorAll('.each-message-box');
    const last = items[items.length - 1];
    if (last) {
      last.scrollIntoView();
    }
  }
```